# Yes or No buttons on confirmation box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, messagebox, confirmation

Below code runs a confirmation box with Javascript on Asp.Net.
I need to change the button texts. How can I use Yes or No buttons with this messagebox?
Thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Confirmation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
   function ConfirmOnDelete() {
    if (confirm("Some question") == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete();" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with `confirm`. There is no way to customize the buttons of the native `alert`/`confirm`/etc dialogs.

You could make a DOM-based dialog instead, and customize the elements to your liking.